# New comment flagging dialog is unusable on Firefox

Tags: bug, design, comment-flags, firefox

In the screenshot below, the flag dialog is positioned so far left and up that most of it is off the screen. Neither the flag options nor the Submit or Cancel buttons are visible.

[image]

Firefox 58.0.1 on Linux

Question in the screenshot: [Struct and pointer to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154179/struct-and-pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: Reproduced on legacy Firefox 56 on Windows. (Don't ask me why I still main legacy Firefox.)

Comment: Also, inb4 "*just* add a userstyle!!1!1"

Comment: Cross-site dupe target on MSE: [Comment flags broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313444/289905). Also, using Firefox Nightly 63.0a1, I’m unable to reproduce this.

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest supported version of Firefox? Running old unsupported versions on the public internet is dangerous.

Comment: @BoltClock: _just add a userstyle!!1!1_

Comment: @RobertLongson FF58 is the latest in Debian repos.

Comment: Related: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/268911).

Comment: No repro in FF 61.0.1. Guess official support is limited to FF 60 and 61 according to Gimby's link.

Comment: You're not missing out on anything, it doesn't look all that good.

Comment: at least you see the remaining flags ... not too bad

Comment: @klutt What your distro supports doesn't matter. If you find (package) updates of your distro are too slow for your liking, you need to switch to another distro.

Comment: @Stijn I just answered the question. :)

Comment: @klutt Fair enough :)

Comment: i could be wrong but isnt that dialog box draggable?

Comment: nevermind, thats the question/answer dialog

Comment: @BoltClock lol "legacy". 56 isn't even a year old. 58 is barely half a year old. This is not "legacy"!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, the progress is getting faster and faster with browsers.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Fx 56 is almost as much a legacy browser next to Fx Quantum 57 as IE11 is to Edge. I am this close to calling Firefox the new IE.

Comment: @BoltClock "Firefox" which, quantum or the non-quantum?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Considering browsers update automagically, nowadays, I'd call the _previous_ version legacy.

Comment: @Cerbrus That is only the case for web browsers connected to, and used for browsing, the world wide web; plenty of other use cases exist. Besides that, auto-update all you want but 6 months ago is still not "legacy".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Browsers that aren't connected to the internet ususally run a web app tailored to the environment. Nice example, but not relevant.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I concede it's not a relevant example, or at least it wouldn't be if we were talking about "legacy in this particular use case". I did provide an additional viewpoint to cover the scenario in which you rejected my first one.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: When a change is so significant that it breaks *every single add-on ever made for the browser up until that point* (some of which I rely on and don't have WebExtensions alternatives), as well as breaking certain sites due to bugs that are specific to the new engine in use, with firm plans to stop supporting all but the ESR version with any further patches, the add-ons and the version(s) of the browser that all those add-ons had always worked for are very much legacy, even if Firefox itself only calls the add-ons "legacy add-ons" and never refers to itself as legacy.

Comment: @BoltClock I'd call that "broken" rather than "legacy". "Legacy" suggests scenarios in which such otherwise-ludicrous antics are okay ;) At least it wouldn't be so bad if they hadn't dropped the useful Major.Minor.Patch version format :(

Comment: Repro in Waterfox 56.2.2, but appears normal when I open developer tools

Comment: No repro on Firefox 61 on Windows 7.

Comment: Here’s a workaround for this issue: Press `Ctrl++`, then `Ctrl+-` (increase/decrease zoom). This will position the dialog in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Somewhat different from @Brian, repro on Windows ***7*** with FF 52.9 (ESR).

Comment: @klutt I'm running 62 for dev edition, 61 normal. 58 is certainly not the most recent on the Debian repos.

Comment: Curiously, I have the opposite problem on my ancient machine running the neolithic Firefox 29.0.1 (don't ask) on a 1024x768 screen: the flag dialog is so far down on the lower right that I have to shrink the font down to an almost unreadable size to be able to get at the Submit button.

Comment: @PM2Ring I won't ask why you're using FF29, but I will say that you should not harbor any hopes of the site working on that version (not that you do currently or anything).

Comment: @TylerH Indeed! I'm slightly amazed that it still works anywhere at all. :) Github tells me it's no longer supported, but it still kinda works for simple stuff.

Comment: @PM2Ring It's only 4 years old! That's... newer than all the people using IE11, at least.

Comment: I don't think you can call an ESR release outdated.  Some might like to, but considering it's what your corporate IT department will be most willing to approve, it needs to be supported.  Firefox ESR 52.9.0 on macOS is able to reproduce.

Comment: I was mistaken yesterday.  I hit "flag" on the question, not on a comment.  Repro in FF 52.5 (ESR) on Windows 10.

Comment: @zero298: In fairness, they did release a new ESR recently, 60. Except it's also the first Quantum-based ESR.

Comment: I also get this on Win 10 Firefox ESR 52.7.3.  Hitting up or down to change the radio button selection snaps it back to the center of the screen, but is still annoying.

Answer (score 4):

As I posted on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313500/388442), I have created a userstyle that fixes it appearing in the top left corner. This requires the [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) add-on and only has been tested on Firefox 56. ([install](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Unannoyingify/master/comment-flag-dialog-bugfix.user.css)) ([source](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Unannoyingify/blob/master/comment-flag-dialog-bugfix.user.css))