# Comment flagging dialog can't be re-opened after flagging

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags

The new comment flagging dialog box can't be re-opened to view how you flagged it or add additional flags after flagging a comment as no longer needed.

I've confirmed this on both Chrome 67 and Firefox 61 on Windows 7.

There's no error dialog, and the cursor does change to make the flag icon look clickable.

If this is by design, please add an error message, or change the UI to make it obvious this can't be clicked. Else, please fix this.

Comment: Maybe its just my old browser, but I find it strange that with the new Code of Conduct and the drive to be more welcoming, that the process of flagging & unflagging is now _much_ harder than it used to be.

Comment: @PM2Ring *Much* harder? How? The process is *exactly* the same. Also, you could never retract a comment flag.

Comment: I was also wondering the same thing (around Jul 24). But yes, it looks like the option has never been there. The persistent flag icon is probably misleading our intuitions. :)

Comment: @NisargShah That indeed addresses one issue. But the other issue, the bad UI, remains. Either there should be an error message, or the flag should not appear clickable and change the cursor when you hover it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I completely agree. Would you mind updating the question?

Comment: @Clint On this old machine, running a 4 year old version of Firefox, the new Flagging dialog is half offscreen, in the lower right corner, making it impossible to click the Submit button, or even to enter a custom flag reason, unless I reduce the screen font size almost to the point of unreadability.

Comment: @Nisarg I've updated it to remove references to retracting flags

Comment: @PM2Ring That's a different issue. It's a bug that may or may not be addressed since only the last 2 major releases are officially supported. See the bug report on that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371840/7296893)

Comment: @PM2Ring Ok... But that has nothing to do with the new code of conduct, the drive to become more welcoming, or the process of flagging. Maybe you should post a separate question with the UI bug you are experiencing.

Answer (score 7):

Checking the code there is a specific class added after flagging the comment `js-flag-disabled`.

[image]

If I manually remove that class I am able to re-trigger the flag popup again (before reloading the page)

[image]

So it's probably a `status-by-design` to have such behavior and they removed the feature to change the type of flag or retract the flag.

Comment: Oh... I hope on an official statement on why we can't retract flags anymore. I wouldn't have a clue why anyone would think removing that feature was a good idea. If I misread or misinterpreted something and realize my error, now I have to wait for a mod to decline my flag (or worse: mark it helpful even though I reconsidered) instead of being able to retract it myself.

Comment: Actually, I don't think we _were_ able to retract comment flags before- At least, I certainly don't recall that. I know we can for posts. (JUdging by https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351632/let-us-finally-retract-flags-on-comments I think this hasn't changes- I can't find, here or the overmeta, a more recent update to that.)

Comment: @Kendra Oh, that might be true. I was almost 100% certain I had retracted comment flags before, but that might be my memory failing, then. A popup or error message might still be helpful, since now it's just a clickable flag that does nothing when clicked.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me that the button just does nothing, when it clearly has the ability to open the flag dialogue box and show what you did to that comment.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Maybe you were thinking of the comment upvote button? You *can* retract upvotes (but only once).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You've never been able to retract comment flags. You can retract post flags, however (at least you could before this change; I haven't tried).

Comment: @TylerH Yes, sorry for the confusion, that has indeed been pointed out to me. I'd still like at least some kind of response when clicking that flag icon (since it looks very clickable), so I left the question around.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth oh I totally agree and wish we could reopen the dialog window and I want an official response as well :-) Was just trying to provide some extra info/clarification to what others were saying.

Answer (score 6):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as the ability to retract comment flags re-adds the ability to view which flag you cast on a comment by reopening the comment flag dialog window.

See [Let us finally retract flags on comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351632/let-us-finally-retract-flags-on-comments)